# Windows app camera not working when installed through windows store

Tags: windows, mobile, tablet

This seems to be a permissions issue. I have an app that when installed through the windows store onto a windows tablet, the camera doesn't work in the app. Its a white blank screen. When I install the app in developer mode with a powershell script, the camera works just fine. Does anyone have an idea of what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Store installation installs with a lot more options than when you installed via PowerShell. I would say that it's one of these options that's causing the unexpected camera behavior, or that it's just a different (misconfigured) version of the app that the developer put on the Windows Store. In any case this issue would be app-specific, so I would encourage you to file a bug report/complaint with the developer of the app telling him about the issue and giving a full description. (Logs of the app would usually help in this case.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try asking the developers about it.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting it. Thank you!